# Lutron Maestro CL Extreme Delay

Tags: led, troubleshooting, dimmer-switch

I've had nothing but success with using Maestro dimmers on both LED and incandescent lighting for years, but recently picked up a new dimmer (MACL-153M-WH) and a pair of G7 Elko LEDs (30W total) and see a strange behavior from the dimmer.

Video to demonstrate: https://youtu.be/_fGK0vBbITU

You'll notice the light level should go to the second indicator from the top when I turn it on.  I press the button, the indicator goes to the middle but the lights on the circuit do not turn on.  Then a couple seconds later it's as though the dimmer resets, the indicator shoots up from the bottom again and the lights come up as originally expected.

The dimmer will be immediately responsive for a while once the lights have come up successfully, but if they sit off long enough the initial delay comes back.

I've tried adjusting the various settings (trim levels, on/off fade times) with no success and reset the dimmer back to factory.

I plan to try switching out the bulbs (never used G7 before) but the dimmer behavior is just generally confusing to me.

---

Update:

- I bought another Maestro CL dimmer from a different location... same
  behavior.
- Bought a pair of G7 Reno bulbs, same behavior.
- Ran to Home Depot and picked up a pair Phillips slim style LED bulbs, *and they work perfectly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See Lutron's list of compatible dimmable LEDs](http://www.lutron.com/technicaldocumentlibrary/3682066_CFL_LED_Bulb_list.pdf). Refer to pages 19-36 for the CL series dimmers.

I do not see any G7 bulbs listed. I would say either your bulbs aren't compatible with your dimmer, or you got a bad dimmer.

Try swapping out whichever is easiest (the bulbs or the dimmer) first, and if that doesn't work try swapping the other.

Comment: Very helpful information.

Comment: @mjohns Good call.

Comment: G7 specifically recommends the Lutron CL which was really the final vote for going with them: http://g7power.com/dimming/

Comment: @roken I see now, the bulb brand is _G7_. I take that to mean Lutron has not tested these bulbs but G7 has tested's Lutron's dimmer. If this is the case, you might just have a bad dimmer.

Comment: Swapped out the G7 bulbs with a different brand of the same wattage load and have no issues with the dimmer.  Will be contacting G7 support.